# Refreshing dataset in PowerBI Service yields DM_GWPipeline_Gateway_MashupDataAccessError

Tags: powerbi, sharepoint-list

I've created a PowerBI dataset that combines data from a Sharepoint List and a dataset from A/S 400 pulled in via an ODBC connection. This dataset works fine in PowerBI desktop. When publishing the report and refreshing the dataset online I run into trouble.

Refreshing the dataset then yields the following error:

```
Data source error: {"error":{"code":"DM_GWPipeline_Gateway_MashupDataAccessError","pbi.error":{"code":"DM_GWPipeline_Gateway_MashupDataAccessError","parameters":{},"details":[{"code":"DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingErrorCode","detail":{"type":1,"value":"-2147467259"}},{"code":"DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingErrorMessage","detail":{"type":1,"value":"The column 'DisplayName' of the table wasn't found."}},{"code":"DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingHResult","detail":{"type":1,"value":"-2147467259"}},{"code":"Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.Detail","detail":{"type":1,"value":"DisplayName"}},{"code":"Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.Reason","detail":{"type":1,"value":"Expression.Error"}}],"exceptionCulprit":1}}} Table: ThirdPartyCapacity.
Cluster URI: WABI-WEST-EUROPE-redirect.analysis.windows.net
Activity ID: 54dc8d30-36e9-46e4-a17e-b233e8eb8ce0
Request ID: 5dd72ecb-2cf2-6082-a9a9-9c8ced7027f7
Time: 2023-07-20 11:11:32Z
```

The A/S 400 data is being fetched via an on-premise data gateway. This gateway is working fine for other reports.

I've made sure and verified that the owner of the dataset has access to the Sharepoint List. The user does not only has edit rights to edit items, but also to edit the list. We can open the list and manipulate it without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks I found the problem.

I've initially configured the dataset to map the Sharepoint via the Gateway. I didn't do that because of a specific reason other then thaat I thought this was necessary. Turns out, you shouldn't. I presume that if you add a gateway mapping to the Lists datasource it routes the connection via the on-premise gateway. Something you don't want for the online Sharepoint environment.

Setting the List mapping blank resolved my issue.